# Could there be a blank space between a section and a subsection?

Tags: typography, thesis

I want to know if the following is allowed, not just in LaTeX, but in some "writing rules", I guess it's a typography matter or some kind of, maybe it could be even different between publications types, anyway I'm writing a thesis.
The example is:

```
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\par Thesis content only here...
```

So the output will be like:

> 1.1 Section
>
> 1.1.1 Subsection
>
> Thesis content only here...

Is the "blank content" between section and subsection a bad practice or not?

Comment: I'd say it is the normal situation. (your `\par` after `\subsection` is odd though, although it does nothing.

Comment: I do not know any ruler at this respect. IMHO, often the introductory paragraph is wrongly omitted, but depend completely on the contents, and the type of manuscript. That you post  this question probably means you find wrong start 1.1.1.  without explain something before.

Comment: BTW, this is really off-topic. The right place to discuss this is in [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72124/bad-style-to-start-text-in-subsection)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is the normal situation.

Your `\par` after `\subsection` is odd though, although it does nothing.
Section headings commands, even run-in headings like `\paragraph` always end in vertical mode so a following blank line (or `\par`) does nothing.